# Deserializing a JSON file with different object types for each key value

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have a json object like this

```
{
  "UrbanSourceUnsealedRoad": 
  [
    {
      "Name": "Baseflow Total Nitrogen Standard Deviation (log mg/L)",
      "Min": "1",
      "Max": "2",
      "Default": "3",
      "AlwaysInReport": "FALSE",
      "Flag": "YES"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Stormflow Total Nitrogen Mean (log mg/L)",
      "Min": "4",
      "Max": "5",
      "Default": "6",
      "AlwaysInReport": "FALSE",
      "Flag": "YES"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "UrbanSourceSealedRoad": 
  [
    {
      "Name": "Baseflow Total Nitrogen Standard Deviation (log mg/L)",
      "Min": "1",
      "Max": "2",
      "Default": "3",
      "AlwaysInReport": "FALSE",
      "Flag": "YES"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Stormflow Total Nitrogen Mean (log mg/L)",
      "Min": "4",
      "Max": "5",
      "Default": "6",
      "AlwaysInReport": "FALSE",
      "Flag": "YES"
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

I have deserialised this using `JSON.net` in C#

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<ParameterInfo>>>(json)
```

This works fine, however now I would like to change the json so that it contains an extra field at the top of the file.

ie:

```
{
    "UrbanLandUse" : ["UrbanSourceMixed", "UrbanSourceSealedRoad", "UrbanSourceUnsealedRoad" ], 
    "UrbanSourceUnsealedRoad": 
    [
        { 
        ...
```

But now my json file is no longer a dictionary containing `List<ParameterInfo>`

The [JSON Spec](http://www.json.org/) seems to indicate that it is indeed possible

But I'm not sure how to deserialize it with the JSON.net API

Can I do this?

Comment: I wonder if I'm not meant to use JSON in this way and I should just go about solving this a different way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a containing object which contains ParameterInfo and the new one you want.
Something like this:

```
public class Container
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<ParameterInfo>> {get; set;}
    public string[] UrbanLandUse {get; set;}
}
```

Then deserialize into that object like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json);
```

Let me know if this works.